# Setting two artists for a song in android

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

How to set two artists for one song in android so that it appears as single artist in playmusic.

I've tried

```
t.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,"ram/Rakul");
t.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM_ARTIST,"ram;Rakul");
t.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM_ARTIST,"ram&Rakul");
```

I Have tried all the seperators, Is there any way to seperate them or we can have only on artist?